# Can't show elements from many to many relationship Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5, database-relations

im trying to query data from a Many to Many relationship in Laravel 5.2 But when I want to retrieve the data im getting blank information. I have some doubts because the data I received only detect `quick_tags` but theres is no data in there and it should be `quickTags`.

I'm doing this in my controller

```
<?php

namespace Knotion\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Knotion\Http\Requests;
use Knotion\Http\Requests\ResourcesRequest;

use Knotion\CTL_Resource;
use Knotion\CTL_Tag;
use Knotion\CTL_QuickTag;
use Knotion\CTL_RelatedTo;
use Knotion\CTL_ResourceType;


class ResourcesController extends Controller  {

    public function index(Request $request)    {

        $resources = CTL_Resource::paginate(10);



        $resources->each(function($resources) {
          $resources->tags;
          $resources->quickTags;
          $resources->relatedTo;

        });

        return response()->json(
          $resources->toArray()
      );
    }
```

and I have this code in my Model

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CTL_Resource extends Model  {
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = "CTL_Resource";
    protected $primaryKey = "idResource";

    protected $hidden = [
      'coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'tags', 'relatedTo',
      'studentVisibility', 'isHTML','studentIndex', 'coachIndex',
      'isURL', 'source', 'path', 'status', 'updateTime', 'isfolder',
      'parentResource', 'idModifierUser'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['idResourceType','productionKey', 'tags', 'idCreatorUser', 'idModifierUser', 'idCreationCountry', 'title', 'description', 'URL', 'fileName', 'extension', 'minimumAge', 'maximumAge', 'productionKey'];

    public function creatorUser() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\OPR_User', 'idCreatorUser');
    }
    public function creationCountry() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_Country', 'idCreationCountry');
    }
    public function resourceType()  {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_ResourceType', 'idResourceType');
    }
    public function quickTags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_QuickTag', 'CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags', 'idResource','idQuickTag');
    }
    public function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_Tag','CTL_Resource_has_Tags', 'idResource', 'idTag');
    }
    public function relatedTo() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_RelatedTo', 'CTL_Resource_has_RelatedTo', 'idResource', 'idRelatedTo');
    }

}
```

This is the result. As you see there is `quick_tags` and its empty

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "idResource": 0,
      "idResourceType": "49ee39d6-eecd-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "idCreatorUser": "04664624-eecd-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "idCreationCountry": "b4afa9ae-eecc-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "productionKey": "1234567890",
      "title": "ElTitle1",
      "description": "ElDescription1",
      "minimumAge": "5",
      "maximumAge": "10",
      "fileName": "ElFileName1",
      "extension": ".png",
      "URL": "ElURL1",
      "createTime": "2016-03-28 14:07:21",
      "quick_tags": []
    },
    {
      "idResource": 0,
      "idResourceType": "49ee39d6-eecd-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "idCreatorUser": "04664624-eecd-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "idCreationCountry": "b4afa9ae-eecc-11e5-b044-4914876a7f3d",
      "productionKey": "0987654321",
      "title": "ElTitle2",
      "description": "ElDescription2",
      "minimumAge": "5",
      "maximumAge": "10",
      "fileName": "ElFileName2",
      "extension": ".png",
      "URL": "ElURL2",
      "createTime": "2016-03-28 14:44:37",
      "quick_tags": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know if its necessary but this is the sql code of the relationship. I just posting this one but others are very similar

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags`;
CREATE TABLE `CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags` (
  `idResource` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to the CTL_Resource table ',
  `idQuickTag` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key to the CTL_QuickTags table.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idResource`,`idQuickTag`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_has_QuickTag_QuickTag1_idx` (`idQuickTag`),
  KEY `fk_CTL_Resource_has_QuickTag_CTL_Resource1_idx` (`idResource`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_has_QuickTag_CTL_Resource1_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`idResource`) REFERENCES `CTL_Resource` (`idResource`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CTL_Resource_has_QuickTag_QuickTag1_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`idQuickTag`) REFERENCES `CTL_QuickTags` (`idQuickTag`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='this table establishes the amount of quicktags that a given tag';
```

Comment: Does the `CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags` table actually exist? I can't see how it would have been created since the fields in that table are `varchar(40)`, but the fields being referenced look to be `int`s. MySQL will error out if you try to create foreign keys to fields with dissimilar types.

Comment: Yes actually exist those tables "CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags" and the others, but I don't like how the others designed the database. I will try to do with migrations or develop by my own. Thanks for the tip, also I suspect about the database. I hope it works. I will let you know. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: How is CTL_Resource.idResource defined? After taking a second look at your output, it seems like it may be a varchar (since your output is showing 0, and I doubt your output is 0). That would also explain how the table exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `idResource` is displaying as 0, as well as some similar fields look like GUIDs and your foreign key fields are defined as `varchar(40)`, I'm going to assume that your `CTL_Resource.idResource` field is also defined as `varchar(40)`.

In this case, when the `$primaryKey` field is not an auto-incrementing integer, you need to tell the Model that. You do this by setting the `$incrementing` property on the Model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Additionally, in relation to your `quick_tags` vs `quickTags` question, that has to do with the `$snakeAttributes` property on your Model. When set to true (which is default), your model will `snake_case` the keys of your relationship objects when converting to json (`toJson()`) or an array (`toArray()`). If you want to turn this off, you need to set the `$snakeAttributes` property on the Model:

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

So, your Model should end up looking something like:

```
class CTL_Resource extends Model  {

    // set the table name since it is not ctl_resources
    protected $table = "CTL_Resource";

    // set the primary key field since it is not id
    protected $primaryKey = "idResource";

    // primary key is not an auto-incrementing int
    public $incrementing = false;

    // no created_at, updated_at fields on this table
    public $timestamps = false;

    // don't snake case the relationship names on json/array conversion
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;

    // code ...
}
```

Comment: OMG! Sir, you are the master! Thank you so much! You helped me a lot! Im so grateful with you. :D